# mpi-selector can't see my mpi libraries

Tags: ubuntu, mpi, openmpi, mpich

I want to use *mpi-selector* which, if I understood well, will allow me to choose my mpi installation. I have got both *openmpi* and *mpich2* installed on my computer (ubuntu 14.04, I run several codes on it and some need mpich and others openmpi). However, when I type :

```
mpi-selector --list
```

I got no answer.
I have seen on the mpi-selector man page that I should source the file mpivars.sh but I can't find these files.
I haven't found which path to put with the *--source-dir* option.
Do you have any idea on how to be able to use both mpi libraries?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you end up solving this issue? If you installed the MPI libraries yourself, you probably need to create your own `mpivars.sh` and `mpivars.csh` files.